# How to adjust size of textarea in Angular2 on page load

Tags: angular

I have a page with several textareas on it. Each textarea/checkbox combo is in a child component.

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="cb_value" [disabled]="cb_disabled" (click)="cbClicked($event)" name="cb"/> 
<textarea [myResizeTextarea]="newText" rows="2" spellcheck="true" class="form-control" [ngModel]="textValue" (ngModelChange)="valueChange($event)" name="textarea" [readOnly]="cb_value" (keypress)="cb_disabled=true;"></textarea>
```

The model "textValue" is retrieved from the server and passed from a parent component.

The directive "myResizeTextarea" currently works for changes to the textarea but the inital textValue is not resizing.

I had added handlers for AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked, AfterContentInit, AfterContentChecked, and OnInit. In them I output the scrollHeight to the console just to check and they were all the default height of the textarea.

How can I adjust the height based on the initial content?

Here is the directive:

```
  export class ResizeTextareaDirective implements OnInit, AfterContentChecked, AfterViewInit, OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() myResizeTextarea: string;  

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {

    this.el.nativeElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    this.el.nativeElement.style.resize = 'none';
  }

  @HostListener('input') onInput() {
    this.resize();
  }
  @HostListener('transitionend') onTransEnd() {
    const scrollHeight = this.el.nativeElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
    console.log('transend scrollheight=' + scrollHeight);
  }
  @HostListener('blur') onChange() {
    const scrollHeight = this.el.nativeElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
    console.log('change scrollheight=' + scrollHeight);
  }

  resize() {
    const scrollHeight = this.el.nativeElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
    console.log('scrollheight=' + scrollHeight);
    this.el.nativeElement.style.height = 'auto';
    this.el.nativeElement.style.height = scrollHeight;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answering diopside. I had logged the heights, but not the styles. I ended up modifiying the directive slightly with this:

```
  initResize = false;
  initialScrollHeight: number;

  ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
  if (!this.initResize) {
      const scrollHeight = this.el.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
      if (scrollHeight !== this.initialScrollHeight) {
        this.resize();
        this.initResize = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

The second pass through the contentChecked event shows the correct scrollHeight so I hacked this in to make it work. Not ideal, and I sure would like to know the correct way to do it, but it works and is good enough. I'll upvote your answer for the help!

Comment: Whatever works! Shouldn't be a problem with the boolean preventing it from being called a million times. Oh and here's a tip that the angular documentation doesn't make very clear - you can use @HostBinding to bind directly to DOM attributes like scrollHeight and clientHeight. You just have to leave off the 'style' or 'attr' prefix.   -->  @HostBinding('scrollHeight') myScrHeight: number = 12345;

Answer (score 0):

Try console.log()'ing

```
 this.el.nativeElement.style
```

from your directive when it loads (either from ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit). I bet you'll find its totally empty except for the resize and overflow values you assigned in the constructor. I don't think Angular, by default, will read all of the styles for an element that you have an ElementRef from, only the ones that are modified. If you do

```
window.getComputedStyle(this.el.nativeElement)
```

Then you'll probably see all of the relevant styles actually populated. That method of reading styles is a real performance killer though, so I usually will find some way to calculate the initial style value I need in the parent, and pass it in as an input and bind to it with HostBinding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was not able to upvote because I am new. See my post below for how I solved it.